# JavaScript remapping data empty array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remap data using JavaScript

```
data[year].map(function(val1,index1){
    for(var prop in val1){
        if (plotdata[prop] === undefined)
            plotdata[prop] = new Array();
        if (plotdata[prop][year] === undefined)
            plotdata[prop][year] = new Array();
        plotdata[prop][year][index1] = val1[prop];
    }
});
```

`data` is an array with a key `"2012"`.

`plotdata` is also an array.

`data['2012']` contains 12 months, indexed from 0 to 11. I am trying to remap the data so I can access it like `plotdata[property][year][month]`, but the problem is that `plotdata` is empty after the mapping.

I have checked and `val1[prop]` does indeed have a value. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Provide a demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: have you tried just stepping through it with a debugger (as is available in any major browser dev tools)?

Comment: Why are you using `Array.map`? Shouldn't be using it if you're throwing away the result, I think you mean to use `Array.forEach`

Comment: This is not your problem, but -- shouldn't `plotdata[prop] = new Array()` actually be `plotdata[prop] = {}`? It doesn't seem like you want an actual array of length 2,013 here.

Comment: @ruakh, that worked actually! If you answer with that solution i will mark it as a solution :)

Comment: @AntonGildebrand: Umm... huh? Why would that make a difference? Oh wait, let me guess. You weren't actually checking if the `plotdata` had members, but were instead relying on `console` output, like `console.log(plotdata);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the above comment-thread . . . this:

```
            plotdata[prop] = new Array();
```

should instead be this:

```
            plotdata[prop] = {};
```

because you want an associative array with years as keys, not a length-2,013 regular array.